# Initialising a class from a number Swift

Tags: swift

A range of basic classes in the foundation framework can be made by simply assigning a basic number to the value where the desired type is known take for example `CGFloat`:

```
let a: CGFloat = 42
```

instead of having to simply use an init like so:

```
let a = CGFloat(42)
```

My question is what is this called when a struct or a class implements this behaviour and how can it be implemented for your own classes.

I don't believe this is matter of CGFloat being a type alias and I cannot seem to find a suitable answer for this.

Comment: I think down voting is a bit harsh. Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question is - "How does the compiler manage to turn `42` into a CGFloat without going through the same process that other values require. i.e `String(someString)`"

Comment: @Abizern yep, exactly

Comment: It would be a good idea to update your question - not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_IntegerLiteralConvertible_Protocol/index.html

Comment: @MartinR perfect! I suspected something like so i should have trawled through the documentation just a bit more, thank you! If you post as an answer ill be happy to accept.

Comment: uh. missed your discussion while putting it together in a playground.

Comment: I had to reach my computer first :) – Note that there is also FloatLiteralConvertible.

Comment: Not to forget StringLiteralConvertible but that may hide important logic if you use it.. (however, you can quite nicely hide converting strings to NSDecimal if you don't care about locale formats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type would need to implement the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol.

That protocol requires you to implement a constructor of the form:

```
init(integerLiteral value: Self.IntegerLiteralType) {}
```

Example:

```
struct MyCoolStruct {
    let value: Int
}

extension MyCoolStruct : IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let instance: MyCoolStruct = 3
instance.value
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4/5:**

IntegerLiteralConvertible has been renamed in ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral:

```
extension MyStruct: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```